# Spring 3.0.5 / Tiles 2.2 Error

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I have a large application used in a production environment. My tiles setup is complex, with many tiles per page. The application works great with the exception of one thing. After starting the server the first page load throws an exception, an error in

```
apache.commons.digester.Digester at line 789/Digester.getParser
```

It throws this:

```
UnsupportedOperationException:: This parser does not support specification "null" version null"
```

The amazing thing is, this error only happens on the first page load, all subsequent loads work just fine. Looking for help with this, let me know what info you need.  Thanks in advance.

This is the nested stack trace:

```
ERROR 08-12-11 15:30:05 (apache.commons.digester.Digester:789) ***Digester.getParser: ***
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setXIncludeAware(SAXParserFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:534)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:786)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:204)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:154)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:54)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:364)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:618)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3498)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.AuthFilterChain$LastFilter.doFilter(AuthFilterChain.java:45)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.AuthFilterChain.doFilter(AuthFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.NegotiateIdentityAsserterServiceImpl.callChain(NegotiateIdentityAsserterServiceImpl.java:145)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.NegotiateIdentityAsserterServiceImpl.process(NegotiateIdentityAsserterServiceImpl.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor679.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
    at $Proxy19.process(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NegotiateIdentityAsserterServletAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(NegotiateIdentityAsserterServletAuthenticationFilter.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.AuthFilterChain.doFilter(AuthFilterChain.java:37)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule$ServletAuthenticationFilterAction.run(SecurityModule.java:612)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.invokeAuthFilterChain(SecurityModule.java:501)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.CertSecurityModule.checkUserPerm(CertSecurityModule.java:97)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.SecurityModule.checkAccess(SecurityModule.java:106)
    at weblogic.servlet.security.internal.ServletSecurityManager.checkAccess(ServletSecurityManager.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2116)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Full Stack Trace (Errors above are nested within this exception):

```
GET /*****_Cust_Search/CustomerDetail?customerId=9 HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: nde-textsize=16px; JSESSIONID_CUSTDETAIL=Bnx0TByHMyvvyDBGb0p9TgCDy1h0n2hlzpckxhdYTsCQ5nJLVSzB!1674277528; ADMINCONSOLESESSION=Gh8nTD9Zpcn26tJBNLVl6q1ZqpQ1jrKTT27ZDL6yLvvvLLC2gjwZ!-975699351; JSESSIONID_CUST=l6GGTGKFYQV1cZ8cnJs2G2891JWclP6FnsDr1vL8bPXvTQpJjn9H!-975699351; JSESSIONID_INSURANCEDETAIL=J1lvTGKQ9G13SM8vYMzG1QPB2R939HQDMgHyJM1GpLG6fyvTJHVX!-975699351; JSESSIONID=gpGtTGYfTKwqh9dG6Q1T305LnbHpGJr6WVNHbx6TQwglXc9lPqgL!-975699351

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:204)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:154)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:54)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:364)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:618)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3498)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

This is the root-context.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/Templates.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is the servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<!--    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">-->
<!--        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>-->
<!--        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />-->
<!--        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />-->
<!--    </beans:bean>-->

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="tiles"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>customer</beans:value> 
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

controllers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="redacted.controllers" />

</beans>
```

tiles.properties

```
CustomerTile.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
CustomerTile.url=CustomerTile
CustomerSearchForm.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
CustomerSearchForm.url=CustomerSearchForm
CustomerSearchResults.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
CustomerSearchResults.url=CustomerSearchResults
EditCustomer.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
EditCustomer.url=EditCustomer
NewCustomer.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
NewCustomer.url=NewCustomer
```

(My Tile Templates) templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/main-container-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="AMHOM" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="normalheader" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="baseLayout2" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/main-container-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="AMHOM" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="custdetailheader" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="baseLayout3" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/main-container-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="AMHOM" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="editcustheader" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="normalheader" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/header-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="menutabs" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/tabs.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="notabsheader" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/header-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="menutabs" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/notabs.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="custdetailheader" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/header-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="menutabs" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_tabs-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="editcustheader" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/header-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="menutabs" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/editcust_tabs-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="completecust" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_complete-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_cpapnav-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="customertile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_content-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="diagtile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_diagnosis-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="resptile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_responsibleparty-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="doctortile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_doctor-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="insurancetile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_insurance-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="customersearch" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/customersearch_complete-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="errors-tile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/customersearchform_errors-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="content-tile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/customersearchform_content-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="custsearchresults" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/custsearchresults_complete-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="errors-tile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/customersearchform_errors-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="content-tile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custsearchresults_content-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="editcust" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/editcust_complete-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/custdetail_cpapnav-tile.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="editcustomertile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/editcust_content-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="newcust" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/newcust_complete-tile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="newcustomertile" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/newcust_content-tile.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="CustomerSearchForm" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="appName" value="Customer Search" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="customersearch" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="CustomerSearchResults" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="appName" value="Customer Search" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="custsearchresults" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="CustomerTile" extends="baseLayout2">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Customer Display" />
        <put-attribute name="appName" value="Customer Display" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="completecust" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="EditCustomer" extends="baseLayout3">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Edit Customer" />
        <put-attribute name="appName" value="Edit Customer" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="editcust" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="NewCustomer" extends="baseLayout3">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="New Customer" />
        <put-attribute name="appName" value="New Customer" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="newcust" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Please show the `spring configuration` and `tilesxyz.xml` file.

Comment: I edited the question and posted the info you requested. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some issue with weblogic windows installation.
Set this value in your `setDomainEnv.cmd` and restart the server.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem today so thought I'd add a post, the problem was because of AppSensor (actually its ESAPI 2.0GA dependency), which comes with two different versions of xerces in its includes (2.6.1 from xom depenency, and 2.8.1 from antisamy dependency), but 2.6.1 comes before 2.8.1 so 2.8.1 is not included and the exception happens.

Fixed by adding a 2.8.1 dependency just before the AppSensor dependency in my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.appsensor</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppSensor</artifactId>
    <version>${appsensor.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - upgrading from 2.6.1 to 2.8.1 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Spring 3.2.1 with tiles 2.2.2 caused the same error. It was solved by updating xerxesimpl. Here is a snippet of the pom.xml

```
        <properties>        
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>            
    <org.slf4j.version>1.5.8</org.slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <xercesImpl.version>2.9.1</xercesImpl.version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <tiles.core.api.servlet.jsp.version>2.2.2</tiles.core.api.servlet.jsp.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you do something stupid like duplicate the  tag at the top of your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.page.definition" template="/WEB-INF/layout/basePageLayout.jsp">
...
```

Hopefully your eyes are sharper than mine and you won't have to come all the way to SO to realize your sloppines....:)